# Fragment Transition API with support library (14+) not doing any transitions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have a larger project in which I need to apply some animations when transitioning between fragments as the user navigates in the app.

So far, I had used method `setCustomAnimation` on the `FragmentTransaction` and it worked great as expected, but it is quite limited when needing to animate views.

So I decided to move on to the Transition API. Good news, it is part of the support library (via AndroidX) and that the `sharedElement` with `transitionName` is also backported. So only one set of code to write and no SDK INT check to do !

However I failed, quite so, and since my project is large, I decided to create a new one, very simple, straight to the point, to see if I am getting it right.

But I not getting it right! So, at this point, I'd like to share my code of this very simple project. If anyone can understand why I don't get transitions, I would be VERY grateful.

Anyway, the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String TRANSITION_NAME = "test_transition_name";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_holder, new FragmentOne(), "FragmentOne")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

As you can see, nothing much, I immediately trigger the process to show my first fragment (`FragmentOne`).

Its layout, anyway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Speaking of fragments, as I said, I went strict to the point, so I have two Fragments, namely `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo`.

Both fragments sports a similar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentOne">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:transitionName="test_transition_name"
        android:text="Hello From Fragment ONE" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentTwo">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:transitionName="test_transition_name"
        android:text="Hello from fragment TWO" />

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, the only differences between these two fragments layout, is the text content (which I made bigger) and the gravity. In `FragmentOne`, text sits on top of the layout while it sits on the bottom in `FragmentTwo`. Nothing fancy all straightforward.

At this point, my aim is to use the Transition API (Android X version) to animate transition between these two texts.

1. When going from `FragmentOne` to `FragmentTwo`, the text slides / moves towards the bottom and
2. when going back, the text slides / moves up (reverse).

Here is the code of these two fragments:

**FragmentOne**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setSharedElementReturnTransition(new AutoTransition());
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view.findViewById(R.id.text_one), MainActivity.TRANSITION_NAME);
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .addSharedElement(view.findViewById(R.id.text_one), MainActivity.TRANSITION_NAME)
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, new FragmentTwo(), "FragmentTwo")
                        .addToBackStack("FragmentTwo")
                        .commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**FragmentTwo**

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.transition.AutoTransition;
import androidx.transition.Transition;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {


    public FragmentTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setSharedElementEnterTransition(new AutoTransition());
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__two, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(view.findViewById(R.id.text_two), MainActivity.TRANSITION_NAME);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There you go. No extra / fancy code here.

In a nutshell:

1. I use the `addSharedElement` on my `FragmentTransaction`. The name is the same as it is the static variable declared in the `MainActivity`
2. As I said, I want to use the Android X library all the way, so all classes are from the Android X packkages and I even use `ViewCompat#setTransitionName` to set the transition name to my shared view while my emulator runs Android 9 Pie.

Where am I getting it wrong ? Why is there no transition at all ?

### [UPDATE 1]

I noticed my layouts for the fragments (which were generated by Android Studio when creating the fragments) had their `TextViews` using `match_parent` for both width and height. So, I guess there isn't much sliding / moving to do as both views have the same bounds (matching the same-sized parents).

I updated my post above with better layouts, but the result is exactly the same.
I even added some background to properly see the views bounds, and set the transition name directly in the XML, though doing that is not backward compatible, but I did for the sake of testing.

Answer (score 1):

I build project from your code. Animations works just perfect. 
The only thing I've notices - in `FragmentOne` you didn't add

```
import androidx.transition.AutoTransition;
```

line so maybe you use `android.transition.AutoTransition` class there. Maybe mistake is there.

It also works without `android:transitionName` lines in xml files (because you almost set it throught `ViewCompat.setTransitionName`) so everything should be backward compatible.

[image]